# Fix required for Jurik RSI Custom Function for Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code Jurik RSX as a custom function in pine script for tradingview but encountering the following error -

> `Mismatched input 'f90_' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'`

My code is as follows -

```
`jrsx(length)=>
f90_ = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) ? 1.0 : (nz(f88[1]) <= nz(f90_[1])) ? nz(f88[1])+1 : nz(f90_[1])+1
f88 = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) and (length-1 >= 5) ? length-1.0 : 5.0 
f8 =  100.0*(src) 
f18 = 3.0 / (length + 2.0) 
f20 = 1.0 - f18 
f10 = nz(f8[1])
v8 = f8 - f10 
f28 = f20 * nz(f28[1]) + f18 * v8 
f30 = f18 * f28 + f20 * nz(f30[1])
vC = f28 * 1.5 - f30 * 0.5 
f38 = f20 * nz(f38[1]) + f18 * vC 
f40 = f18 * f38 + f20 * nz(f40[1])
v10 = f38 * 1.5 - f40 * 0.5 
f48 = f20 * nz(f48[1]) + f18 * v10 
f50 = f18 * f48 + f20 * nz(f50[1])
v14 = f48 * 1.5 - f50 * 0.5 
f58 = f20 * nz(f58[1]) + f18 * abs(v8) 
f60 = f18 * f58 + f20 * nz(f60[1])
v18 = f58 * 1.5 - f60 * 0.5
f68 = f20 * nz(f68[1]) + f18 * v18 
f70 = f18 * f68 + f20 * nz(f70[1])
v1C = f68 * 1.5 - f70 * 0.5 
f78 = f20 * nz(f78[1]) + f18 * v1C 
f80 = f18 * f78 + f20 * nz(f80[1])
v20 = f78 * 1.5 - f80 * 0.5
f0 = ((f88 >= f90_) and (f8 != f10)) ? 1.0  : 0.0
f90 = ((f88 == f90_) and (f0 == 0.0))  ? 0.0  : f90_
v4_ = ((f88 < f90) and (v20 > 0.0000000001)) ? (v14 / v20 + 1.0) * 50.0 : 50.0
rsx = (v4_ > 100.0) ? 100.0 : (v4_ < 0.0) ? 0.0 : v4_`
```

Please help me to solve it.

I have written the code but got no clue how to fix it to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indent each line in your function's body by 4 spaces or 1 tab. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Declaring_functions.html) for more information regarding the functions in `pinescript`.